# Bootstrap w/ ng-disabled Not Visually Disabling Button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my app without CSS. Notice that the buttons are obviously disabled.

[image]

Then, here's what it looks like after adding Twitter Bootstrap:

[image]

I verified that the buttons are disabled. However, why do they look enabled?

Comment: can you please put your code in plnkr or fiddle. Its hard to comment without having a looking at the code

Answer (score -1):

Improper use may be somewhere

You can try using the button ng-disabled

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled